# Is it possible to stop an MDB from receiving messages in Liberty Profile?

Tags: jms, websphere-liberty, message-driven-bean

In a full WAS it is possible to stop and restart a JMS activation specification, either by using the administrative console or by using the J2CMessageEndpoint MBean. My question is if the J2CMessageEndpoint MBean will be available in Liberty Profile, making it possible to pause an activation specification?

If not, is there any other way that I can activate/deactivate the message endpoint in Liberty Profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a direct equivalent, but you can change the server xml so the activation specification binding no longer matches. When the server picks up the new configuration, which is dynamic by default, the binding won't match and the mdb will stop.

Comment: I tried it and it works :-) Provided that ”updateTrigger=disabled” is not set. But shouldn’t this be considered as a short-time solution or a workaround? I mean, injecting an error in the configuration does not seem right even if it prevent the MDB from receiving messages.

Comment: It is a workaround, but the only option right now. There is likely an RFE in the system to add the mbean.

Comment: Great. Then I will use the workaround while I'm awaiting the RFE to become a reality.

Comment: any updates to this one? I mean, is there an mBean action what the code within the application can invoke, so that the application will dis-connect itself from the msgs