# Is there any option to activate/deactivate a MDB in open liberty

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mq, open-liberty

I have an enterprise application where I have defined around 10 Message-Driven Beans (MDBs), and I would like to activate them only when necessary, keeping them deactivated otherwise. I will do the required configuration in `server.xml`, `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml`, and `ejb-jar.xml`, and I would like to know if there is any flag kind of option to enable/disable the required MDBs.

Sample config shown below,

**ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml**

```
    <message-driven name="channel1TransactedMDB">
      <jca-adapter activation-spec-binding-name="jms/channel1MessageMDB" destination-binding-name="jms/channel1Queue"/>
      <resource-ref binding-name="jms/ConnectionFactory" name="jms/QueueConnectionFactory"/>
      <message-destination-ref binding-name="jms/channel1ReplyQueue" name="jms/ReplyQueue"/>
     </message-driven>
     <message-driven name="channel2TransactedMDB">
      <jca-adapter activation-spec-binding-name="jms/channel2MessageMDB" destination-binding-name="jms/channel2Queue"/>
      <resource-ref binding-name="jms/ConnectionFactory" name="jms/QueueConnectionFactory"/>
      <message-destination-ref binding-name="jms/channel2ReplyQueue" name="jms/ReplyQueue"/>
   </message-driven>
```

**server.xml**

```
   <jmsQueue id="jms/channel1Queue" jndiName="jms/channel1Queue">
     <properties.wasJms  queueName="channel1Queue" />
    </jmsQueue>
    <jmsQueue id="jms/channel1ReplyQueue" jndiName="jms/channel1ReplyQueue">
     <properties.wasJms  queueName="channel1ReplyQueue" />
    </jmsQueue>

    <jmsQueue id="jms/channel2Queue" jndiName="jms/channel2Queue">
     <properties.wasJms  queueName="channel2Queue" />
    </jmsQueue>
    <jmsQueue id="jms/channel2ReplyQueue" jndiName="jms/channel2ReplyQueue">
     <properties.wasJms  queueName="channel2ReplyQueue" />
    </jmsQueue>

    <jmsActivationSpec id="jms/channel1MessageMDB">
     <properties.wasJms destinationRef="jms/channel1MessageMDB" destinationType="javax.jms.Queue" />
    </jmsActivationSpec>
    <jmsActivationSpec id="jms/channel2MessageMDB">
      <properties.wasJms destinationRef="jms/channel2MessageMDB" destinationType="javax.jms.Queue"/>
    </jmsActivationSpec>
```

I have found a workaround in the below link, but would like to know if this feature is available now,

[Is it possible to stop an MDB from receiving messages in Liberty Profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086756/is-it-possible-to-stop-an-mdb-from-receiving-messages-in-liberty-profile)

Expecting a configuration that could activate or deactivate my MDB as and when required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the `jmsActivationSpec` with `autoStart` set to false which will stop the MDB starting automatically. When you have a stopped MDB you can use the [ServerEndpointControl](https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/content/SSD28V_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.liberty.doc/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.kernel.service_1.1-javadoc/com/ibm/websphere/kernel/server/ServerEndpointControlMBean.html) MBean to `resume` the MDB. You can also use `server resume` to do the same on the command line.